# Android decimal formatting, How to make decimal formatting based on different exponential value?

Tags: java, android, numbers, number-formatting

I am developing unit conversion application and need to make decimal formatting proper for different exponential values.

1. Suppose if answer is 1e-6 answer should be 0.000001
2. Suppose if answer is 2.1345e3 answer should be 2134.5
3. Suppose if answer is 2.13456e-9 answer should stay 2.13456e-9
4. Suppose if answer is 1987.345e-3 answer should be 1.98734e-6

I have attached iphone and android decimal formatting images.
[ios and android number formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wICHr.jpg)

[image: ios and android number formatting]

As you can see in android formatting is same for all the values, but i need different formatting for different values.

Please let me know if need more information. Following is my code for formatting in android, all the values are in double only.

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("######.#####E+0");
 String answer = df.format(value);
 return answer;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As you want different formats for different sizes you can divide the continuum into different areas and match each area to its format. For example (I am not sure if patterns make any sense, but the idea is simple enough):

```
public String myFormat(double value) {
    String pattern;

    if (value > 1) {
        pattern = "######.#E+0";
    } else if (value > 0.01) {
        pattern = "#.#####E+3";
    } else {
        pattern = "######.#####E+0";
    }

    return new DecimalFormat(pattern).format(value);
}
```